# Ubuntu 12.04 - Bumblebee 3.1 - Error - Unable to locate package Bumblebee

Tags: bumblebee

Hello Ubuntu citizens,

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (up-to-date) and was trying to install the new Bumblebee 3.1

First, I tried to remove Bumblebee first using:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge 
sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

Then I re-install using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

The last command gave me error:

```
ux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee-nvidia
```

What did I do wrong?

I looked around for a couple hours but got nothing.  Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 2):

After hours of googling to no avail, I managed to solve it:

Go to Update Manager > Settings... > Other Software (tab) > (tick both) Bumblebee PPAs

Apparently, using the purge commands somehow unticked them.  Hope this will help someone.